# Ruby version conflict while using pik in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pik

I'm working on a project that runs Rails Backend. I'm using Pik for managing the Ruby versions. But when I try to run the server, terminal shows following error:

```
C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity>rails s -p 3001
Your Ruby version is 3.0.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity>ruby --version
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]
```

You can clearly see here that 2.7.2 is the version currently being used here but it still shows the error.
Also, the Ruby version mentioned in Gemfile is:

```
ruby "2.7.2"
```

Can you please guide me about the reason behind this?

**Note:** I've installed Ruby 2.7.2 in my Local Disk (D) and then added this via this command:

```
pik add D:\Ruby27-x64/bin
```

**Edit:** Also, installed this Ruby version in Local Disk (C) after uninstalling from Disk (D). But the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you find it surprising that you have problems with a tool that explicitly tells you in its documentation that you should not use it because it is no longer maintained?

Comment: But the issue seems to be something else. As you can see that it has set the ruby version 2.7.2 perfectly(See second query in terminal). But it still shows that you're using 3.0.1. Both above queries are contradictory to one another. Also, please suggest me some alternate for windows.

Comment: `rvm` or possibly `uru` (not used the latter, but some websites advise it's use) https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/wiki/browse/